# Multiple services with same interval of time in android

Tags: android

How to run multiple services in background with same interval of time in android? . I tried with AlarmManager but in this it is not running with same intervals like every 5 mins(Sometimes its running correctly but not all the times). Please suggest me best way to achieve this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why are they multiple services? Why is it not one service that does multiple things?

Comment: thanks @CommonsWare . i will do that but different services with different time not running with exact time difference can u please tell me what is the reason .

Comment: i am calling some rest call every 5 min and 2 mins but it is not calling with exact 2 and 5 minutes.sometime its calling with exact time but sometime its taking 10 to 15 min to call

Comment: From the documentation of alarm manager: 

Note: Beginning with API 19 (KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use. There are new APIs to support applications which need strict delivery guarantees; see setWindow(int, long, long, PendingIntent) and setExact(int, long, PendingIntent). Applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to see the previous behavior in which all alarms are delivered exactly when requested.

Comment: Thanks @bogdanN is these methods calling repeatedly ?

Comment: "i am calling some rest call every 5 min and 2 mins but it is not calling with exact 2 and 5 minutes.sometime its calling with exact time but sometime its taking 10 to 15 min to call" -- correct. You cannot do anything that frequent and that exact on modern Android devices, because it is bad for the battery, and users have been complaining. Either rewrite your system to focus on server push (GCM/FCM) or rewrite your system to deal with variable delays (with Doze mode/app standby, measured in hours) between events.

Comment: thanks @CommonsWare i will try , is it possible to share any link ?

Comment: Share a link to... what?

Comment: @CommonsWare to handle variable delays

Comment: We cannot give you any specific information as your information is too generic. We don't really know what you're trying to achieve

Comment: @bogdanN i am trying call rest apis even application is killed

Answer (score -1):

```
    To run the multiple services in particular interval, you can use timertask

    Timer timer =new Timer();

    TimerTask  timerTask= new TimerTask() {
           public void run() {
            //TODO
           }
    };


   timer.schedule(timerTask, 1000, 1000);


Example for Service,

public class ServcieSample extends Servcie{

public void onCreate(){
}
}

Inside onCreate you can create any number of threads or asynctask for background operations.
```

Comment: Services will run on Main thread only (not in the background), If we want to do any background operations, you need to create threads or async task in service.

Comment: Then How we can do some operation even app is killed ?

Comment: We can use services for non UI operation but service will be running on Main thread only.